# New attack method spreading on #Solana can i get help ? solana!

Tags: solana-program, solana-wallet-adapter, bug, developer

my address get owner change or something call fee payer bcs the address  this naver happend to me i am useing solana +2 year
here detail how my address changed owner and is there anything can i do to revoke it ?

trx detail : https://solscan.io/tx/589QVemJoKdfbfc7ZSSxFuhfGydTE7Lx8SvR1yEwNkcHNKPZfqQxrRJwMabYoZg5xAqY9JXrfNAEn4BawejUVroj
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site is not for wallet support

Comment: Do you remember which site this wallet drainer was on?